# Nested for loop saving last input not whole input

Tags: c, arrays, variable-length-array

I'm back again with that C question heh. So I'm trying to get the user to input a whole 2d array (size, values, everything), with VLA arrays (im using the latest compiler). Everything is fine up until I get the nested for loop, then it saves the last value into the array and ignored anything before it. I cannot seem to figure out how to fix my VLA to iterate through every element in the array and assign the value typed in by the user, all I get is it saving my last value into the whole array. Through some testing I've found that my problem is contained in my Inner loop of my nested for loop. EDIT: Through the help of Weather Vane, it was figured out that the array needs to be initialized after my x and y are saved, but now it saves my last value in the whole array and not every value typed.  Here's my code snippet:

```
   int x, y, row, col, a = 0;
   //int NxM[x][y]; Moved 
   bool counter[10]; //I have 1 last part to code that involves this

   printf("This program counts occurrences of digits 0 through 9 in an NxM 
   array.\n");

   printf("Enter the size of the array (Row Column): ");
   scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
   int NxM[x][y]; //Moved here.
   for(row = 0; row < x; row++){
       printf("Enter row %d: \n", a);
       a++;
      for(col = 0; col < y; col++){


               scanf("%d ", &NxM[x][y]);//Why you only save 1 value >.<
        }


   }
```

(The reason I have my printf statement between my loops was to test where my looping problem was, and because I need my printf to look like `Enter row 0 Enter row 1` etc..)

Comment: `int NxM[x][y];` is using undefined values. Move it down below `scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);` and check the return value from `scanf` as well as the values too. Suppose  Noddy enters `-1 -2` ?

Comment: x and y are initialized above, should I set them equal to 0?

Comment: Nope, they are not initialised before `int NxM[x][y];` . C is not a forward-thinking language. It does not wait until later and track what you are doing. It uses the values it knows for `x` and `y` at the time you use them.

Comment: So. You just fixed my problem............................... I feel so dumb. OH so because x and y were basically just floating variables when the array was put in, they werent used in the evaluating of the dimensions of the array in my for loop, or am i off base completely?

Comment: Alright that fixed my for loop, unfortunately, now when it iterated through my loop it saves the final input in the whole array. (say the user last inputs 4, the whole array is 4)

Comment: Please ask a **new question** showing how you know that.

Comment: Kinda figured it'd be iffy to try and edit my question with my new information heh, I'll ask a new question.

Comment: This is not a dynamic code-adjusting site, sorry. It is for questions that may interest other coders too, rather than being a personal service. So, when you change the question what use is that?

Comment: Never thought of it that way really, I seem hella selfish now, honestly I was just sweet got that answered but when I ran into another question, I asked myself if I ask a question every time I run into something I cannot figure out there'd be 500 questions from just me, so why not edit the 1 i posted save some space.

Comment: Add a EDIT section to the question itself.  Do NOT ask another question in the comments

Comment: when asking a question about a runtime problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and determine the root cause.